# Slow wifi connection on certain device

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I had problem, that one laptop had really slow wifi connection. After router restart was connection OK but only few days (1-3). Then after 3 months somehow problem disappeared. A few moths was everything ok and now, I have got the same problem with another laptop. It is not new, I am using it 6 months. All other devices works well. I found some advices, but they all talk about HW problem... Could it be some bad Win10 update? My wifi driver was not updated for more then 1 year and I have got the last version of it, so it should not be a problem. It should not be HW problem as well, connection with another wifi spot is fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Updates have been fairly reliable.

For the 2 problem devices here, do two things:

**1. Driver Update:** Get the computer manufacturer's Driver Update App and update all drivers that you can.  Be sure to update Wireless and then I do all others including BIOS.

**2. Run TCP/IP Reset, DNS Flush**.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: I ran  TCP/IP Reset, so far so good. Let`s wait a few days, how it works. Thank you @John

Comment: That should work - thank you. I have does this reliably for customers.